# Change CSS of ID depeding on other ID's src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If 'maps', 'src' changes to "sunday\'s Labour.html", why would the color of '#sunday' not change to green?  My code is as below:

```
if(document.getElementById('maps').getAttribute('src') == "sunday\'s Labour.html"){
    $('#sunday').css({
     'color': 'green'
    });
  };
```

Further up in my code I have this (the myUrlArray is a list of strings like above):

```
setInterval(function(){
    var u = 0;
    document.getElementById('maps').setAttribute('src',myUrlArray[u]);
    if(u < myUrlArray.length){
        ++u;
    }else{
        u = 0;
    }
  },3000);
```

Final edit, this worked when I put the 'if' inside the setInterval, like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var u = 0;
    document.getElementById('maps').setAttribute('src',myUrlArray[u]);
    if(u < myUrlArray.length){
        ++u;
    }else{
        u = 0;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('maps').getAttribute('src') == "sunday\'s Labour.html"){
        $('#sunday').css({
         'color': 'green'
    });
  };
  },3000);
```

Comment: `src` attribute should belong to `<img>` tag only, guess your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Its working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/2xw7P/

Comment: Sorted this, I had to put the 'if' statement inside the setInterval function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your Javascript. I tested the script and found that the `\` in `sunday\'s Labour.html` is causing the problem.Remove it and it will work correctly.

With `\` in `sunday\'s Labour.html` : http://jsfiddle.net/G5XPJ/

Without `\` : http://jsfiddle.net/G5XPJ/1/

Comment: What's the difference between this and his version except using jquery?

Comment: In my answer i wrote "try".I myself is testing it in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Zword This didn't work for me, I have elaborated on my question a little. see edit.

Comment: Remove "\" .Your edited question with the added part of setInterval() still contains "\" in the src url

Comment: And just to clear doubt , are you using external jquery.js for using JQuery?If not add `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>` in the head section of your page.